# Paypal Rounding Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, paypal, rounding

Does anyone know what algorithm Paypal uses to round? I'm doing some testing with discount promo codes on my site, and I'm coming up with different totals than what Paypal comes up with when I pass the same discount amount using the "discount_rate_cart" variable.

For example, a couple of items on my site total $309.95.  Applying a 10% discount ( 309.95 * .9 = 278.955) should yield a total of $278.96, as .955 should round up to .96. However, when I pass the total $309.95 and the 10% discount to PayPal, they come up with a total of $278.95. They rounded down when they should have rounded up.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Please note, I'm not doing anything fancy like currency conversion here, just simple algebra for giving discounts on the total cost of the shopping cart.

Comment: Perhaps they are doing 309.95 * .1 = 30.995, which rounds up to 31. Then 309.95 - 31 = 278.95.

Comment: They should be using 'banker's rounding', i.e. ROUND_HALF_EVEN. If they aren't, file a bug report. They are a bank after all.

Answer (score 1):

So the algorithm is banking rounding but on a transaction by transaction basis. This means the discount is a transaction of its ow e.g.

10% of $309.95 is $30.995 and bank rounding is to the nearest **even** number being $31.00.

Therefore:

```
 $309.95
-$ 31.00
========
 $278.95
```

So theoretically if you had a discount of $30.987 this will round to $30.98 **not** $30.99.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what other figures spit out to see if my algorithm holds.

Comment: Thanks for the answers EJP and glh.  Now I just need to figure out how to implement banking rounding in PHP...

Comment: Good work.  For anyone that's interested, `number_format(round($price,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN),2)` seems to work nicely in PHP if you want to keep everything to 2 decimal places.  e.g. `number_format(round(30.995,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN),2) = 31.00`

Comment: 30.987 id a wrong choice: it is rounded to 30.99 in half even method. That's ok because the half even rule only differs on how is treated a 5 in third decimal (when rounding to 2 decimals): 
if 5 is followed by at least one number that is not 0: rounds up
if 5 is last decimal and preceded by an even number: round down
and if 5 is last decimal and preceded by an odd number: round up.
Give a try with following examle : 30.985 is rounded up to 30.99 with classic half up rounding, and rounded down to 30.98 with half even rounding, whereas 30.9851 and 30.975 is rounded up to 30.98 in both cases